# How to fix 'AttributeError: Unknown property figsize'?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple graphs into 1 using a for loop and I encountered this problem. I tried it for the other loops and it works just fine but I don't know what happened with this one.

The files used are the exchange rates of EUR to USD for the past 2 years and I am trying to plot the date and the price on the graph. If I don't use figsize the graph is too small but it works.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = ['somefile.csv', 'otherfile.csv', 'anotherfile.csv']

for files in file:

    files1 = pd.read_csv ('%s' %files)

    files1.plot (kind='line', x='Date', y='Price', ax=ax, figsize=(15,10))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 10):

One way around is using

```
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(15, 8)
```

So your code should be

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = ['somefile.csv', 'otherfile.csv', 'anotherfile.csv']

for files in file:

    files1 = pd.read_csv ('%s' %files)

    files1.plot (kind='line', x='Date', y='Price', ax=ax)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(15, 8))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You should, we just need to set the size of figure once we are done plotting. plt.gcf() will get a handle on the figure, using which we can set the size and do a alot of other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following: Create first the axis object specifying the figure size and then use that object while plotting

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))

for files in file:
    files1 = pd.read_csv ('%s' %files)
    files1.plot (kind='line', x='Date', y='Price', ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to specify axis as ax(ax=ax), best answer would be @Sheldore's. But there's actually an easier, also the most basic, way to this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
```

Put this before the for loop.